# Missing contents in html when crawling website with mechanize/selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-crawler, mechanize

I'm trying to scrape infos from this page:
http://www.repertoireconservatoires.fr/repertoire/?instrument=&region=67%2C68&etablissment_type=

Using all the tools that I have (beautifulSoup, mechanize, selenium) and having bought a day access to the content, I haven't been able to get the full HTML page as displayed in the source code in my browser.
Here's what it looks like in chrome

```
<!-- featured news area on homepage template if applied -->
    <div class="latest-news-homepage" role="complementary">

        <div class="section-inner-container">
    <div class="archive-wrapper">

        <!-- si:resultat -->
            <h2 class="nb_resultats">132 établissements trouvés</h2>                        
                <h3 class="archive-title">Liste des établissements 
        correspondant à votre recherche :</h3>
                <ul class="archive-post-list">
        <!-- repeat:repertoire -->

        [...]

        <!-- /repeat:repertoire -->

        <!-- /si:resultat -->

                        </ul>
                    </div>  
            </div>

        </div>
        <!-- /. end of featured-news container -->
```

And here's what I get as a response from mechanize or selenium:

```
<!-- featured news area on homepage template if applied -->
    <div class="latest-news-homepage" role="complementary">

            <div class="section-inner-content">

<div class="archive-wrapper"> 



                </div>  

        </div>

    </div>
    <!-- /. end of featured-news container -->
```

So there's nothing inside that 'archive-wrapper' class (not sure about the terminology here).
I quite get from the comment that something seems to be withholding the content, but I don't really know what nor why.
I am very unfamiliar with coding, but here's what I came up with:

```
import mechanize
import cookielib

url = 'http://www.repertoireconservatoires.fr/repertoire/?instrument=&region=67%2C68&etablissment_type=&page=0'

cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)
br.open(url)
br.select_form(nr=0)
br.form['ticket'] = PASSWORD
br.submit()
print br.response().read()
```

and this with selenium, hoping the browser emulation would be enough:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()

# submit a login form
username = driver.find_element_by_name('ticket')

username.send_keys(PASSWORD)

username.submit()

print driver.page_source
```

The 1 day access code (PASSWORD in the code) is H2CB-LLL9, it'll be expired in a few hours anyways, so if it might help...
Hope you can get me out of this one :p 
I've been using the search function a lot to get to this code already but I couldn't find the solution for my issue here.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Can you provide full code for example iwth selenium?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry I'm just very dumb, here's the solution:

```
    url = 'http://www.repertoireconservatoires.fr/repertoire/?
        instrument=&region=67%2C68&etablissment_type='
    cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
    br = mechanize.Browser()
    br.set_cookiejar(cj)
    br.open(url)
    br.select_form(nr=0)
    br.form['ticket'] = 'H2CB-LLL9'
    br.submit()
    br.select_form(nr=0)
    br.form['region'] = ['67,68']
    br.submit()
    co = br.response().read()
    print co
```

I was just filling the password and then submitting, not entering any value in the drop down menu, so I was getting empty results.
Thanks for trying to help, my bad.
I'm glad I figured it out though it took me way too much time